# How to setup an MVC website to use the same SSO as CRM Online, so that it can be IFramed?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, dynamics-crm-online

Currently using CRM Online w/ a Single Sign On for AD Authentication.  I need to create an Asp.Net MVC site that I iFrame into CRM, but I want it to utilize the same SSO so if the user is "signed into" CRM, the iFrame'd page will utilize the same credentials, and not require the user to sign in.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following article useful.

[Implement single sign-on from an ASPX webpage or IFRAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061(v=crm.8).aspx).

> The typical use of this capability is to write a webpage that is
>   displayed in an inline frame in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM web
>   application user interface. That webpage performs its intended
>   operation, for example, providing a store front, while being hosted on
>   a website independent of the site that’s hosting CRM. However, the
>   webpage can perform its operations on behalf of the CRM user who is
>   signed in. The result is seamless integration between a webpage and
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM.