# Programmatically Check if User Authenticated to Office 365/CRM Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have an ASP.NET page hosted on an external web server that is embedded in an iFrame within the Contact Form in CRM Online. As of right now, the page shown in the iFrame is accessible to the entire web, but I would like to restrict access to just users that are authenticated to CRM Online / Office 365. Is there a way for me to programmatically check to see if a user is authenticated to CRM Online/Office 365 from my external application? I'm not interested in implementing/authenticating users within my iFrame itself, but rather I'd just like to see if they have a valid login session and if so, display the page, and if not, hide it. Any feedback or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe SAML could do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case its probably easiest to do the following:

1. Setup your web page to capture user authentication details - you will need to do this recognise who the user is. This will largely depend on what authentication method you are using. For example, with Windows Authentication you could get the user domain name, i.e. `MyDomain\james.wood`.
2. Then query CRM via web services to check if that user (based on domain name for example) has an system user with security roles, or specific privileges.

This way you don't have to worry about seeing if they are actually logged into CRM. You just check if the user has access to data in CRM. You could look into adding additional checks so that if the web page is opened outside of a CRM iframe, you don't show the web page content. Additionally you could go even further and impersonate the user in any web service calls to CRM.

You may find the following useful.

- [Authenticate users in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497.aspx).
- [Sample: Determine whether a user has a role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602961.aspx).
- [Impersonate another user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx).

---

Edit

Alternatively you could look to implement single sign on.

[Implement single sign-on from an ASPX webpage or IFRAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061(v=crm.8).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been able to prompt for credentials and verify authentication to the CRM Web Services. However, we were hoping to avoid re-prompting for credentials and instead use the existing CRM Online/Office 365 login session/"token" since the user has already authenticated. I'm not sure if there's a way to "pass" the session into our application that runs within the iFrame or make some sort of call from our iFrame to a token endpoint to determine if the user is authenticated. Maybe even a cookie we could read from the browser?

Comment: @JoshMorton, I think you want single sign on then, see my edit

Comment: I'm guessing you're link at the bottom is the answer to my question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056199/how-to-setup-an-mvc-website-to-use-the-same-sso-as-crm-online-so-that-it-can-be

Comment: @Daryl, possibly - not done it myself in that way - I was just aware of the article, I've added an answer to your question for others.